# Fast methods for adding the basepoint to an elliptic curve point?

Tags: elliptic-curves, ed25519, elliptic-curve-generation, x25519, montgomery-multiplication

Are there any clever (fast) methods for adding the basepoint (generator) to an arbitrary point on elliptic curve, finally ending in affine coordinates?
I.e. if `G` is the generator for a group on the curve (e.g. 25519) and `P` is an arbitrary point, is there a faster-than-naive way to find `P + G` in affine coordinates?

I'm interested in quickly enumerating the points on a curve, starting with `G`, then `2G`, `3G`, etc, with final values in affine coordinates.

My current solution starts with `G` and `P` in Edwards coordinates and then converts `G + P` to affine coordinates (which is slow). But I figure there might be some magic that 1) takes advantage of `G` being known or 2) uses the work previously done when computing the sequence `G`, `2G`, `3G`, etc.

Thank you!

EDIT: To be clear, I'm not interested in scalar multiplication of an elliptic curve point by a number (I don't want to compute `nG` for arbitrary `n`). Instead I want to "increment" a point `P` by adding it with the generator `G`.

Comment: Are you looking more than the double-and-add algorithm which is additive version of square-and-multiply? You can look at Wikipedia page [Point Multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Point_multiplication),

Comment: We have many Q/A for this like [Scalar Multiplication on Elliptic Curves](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/11743/18298) or search for ["doube-and-add"](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22double-and-add%22) on our site. OR, [How does one calculate the scalar multiplication on elliptic curves?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3907/18298)

Comment: Or, you might be looking or something like this [Advantages of Montgomery Ladder-based Scalar Multiplication](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/47895/18298) since you have tagged x25519.. and [What is a u-coordinate within Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman using the Montgomery ladder](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/47409/18298)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I don't think any of that is what I'm looking for, and I've updated the question text to make that clearer.

Comment: To be more clear, are you looking for $P+G$ or $P+[2]G$ or $P+[k]G$ for an unknown $k$ to be determined?

Comment: I'm looking for `P + G` for unknown `P` and generator `G`. Alternatively, I'd like a quick algorithm for finding the sequence `G`, `2G`, `3G`, ...

Comment: What do you mean by unknown $P$? And, the obvious part for $G, [2]G,\text{ and }, [3g], \ldots$ is starts from double-and-add to Joyce-ladder to Montgomery ladder for DHKE...